# Jint Array functions ECMA 5.1

Tags: c#, ecmascript-5, jint

I'm attempting to use Jint (v2.10.4.0) to translate one arbitrary JSON structure to another. However, I am having issues with using **map**.

According to the ECMA 5.1 language spec, [map](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19) should exist on Array.prototye. However, when I attempt to use it, I get an error: **Jint.Runtime.JavaScriptException:** 'Object has no method 'map''

I'm testing this like

```
Engine engine = new Engine();
var doubles = engine.SetValue("x", "[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]")
    .Execute("x.map(function(a){ return a + a; })")
    .GetCompletionValue()
    .ToObject();
Console.WriteLine(doubles);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Ideally, I'd also like to use find, although this is ECMA6. Is there something I'm missing to use Array.Prototype.map or is there a way of introducing polyfills for Jint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is adding a string value as `x`, so Jint can't find `map` on the string instance. You probably assumed that the `SetValue` method was evaluating the parameter as a script but it's actually just assigning a .NET object to a JavaScript varialble.

To assign an array you either need to pass a C# array like `SetValue("x", new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })` or run the equivalent script like `Execute("var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]")`.

Comment: Thanks. I did eventually figure this out!