# How can I use underscore functions in Jint

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, jint

I'm using Jint for executing javascript in my c# project and I need to access functions like map, filter, reduce etc on an Array.
From what I've been able to find here, the native array functions are not available in Jint, but, underscore.js is included in the Jint package, but how do I access it to use _.map() etc?

As a corollary, I would like to use arrow functions for the conditions in functions like filter, but Jint currently complains about > being an unexpected character.

I'm using the v3.0.0-Beta-1138 nuget package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use arrow functions because it's a `ES6` feature and `Jint` provides `ES5`

from : https://github.com/sebastienros/jint

> Jint is a Javascript interpreter for .NET which provides full ECMA 5.1
>   compliance

but array functions like `map` should be there, check this answer maybe this could be your issue :

[Jint Array functions ECMA 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44236341/jint-array-functions-ecma-5-1)